# Table of t-stats

Tags: datatables, stata, economics

I have a list of t-statistics for several variables: e.g. t-statistic1, t-statistic2, t-statistic3.

How do I make a nicely formated table in Stata with two columns: one that is the name of the variable that I write in (e.g. "Housing", "Food", "Water") and the other column is t-statistic, which is the list of t-statistics (t-statistic1, t-statistic2, etc).

I tried using `ssc install` but it didn't work.

Comment: `ssc install` won't work unless you specify some package to install. Otherwise `edit` is the way to type in new variables (which you call columns) if I understand your question.

Comment: how would you use the edit function?

Comment: `edit` is a command, and so `help edit` is a place to start. It points to the Getting Started volume(s): choose that for your OS.